How to parse and return a specific section of the clipboard?
I need to pull out a specific section of the clipboard data.
Characters 235 - 242 are all I need and anything before or after that isn't needed.
I'm using xsel to retrieve the clipboard data, but how can I trim this to only those characters?
I'm a newbie so I don't know what command-line tools can achieve this.

You can use the cut utility to extract a substring.  This is normally a line-oriented command, but we can change it to use a null character as line separator with the -z option.  Assuming you don't have any nulls in your clipboard text, that will make it index into the full content.
xsel --clipboard | cut -z -c235-242

